# Slate library for writing phonograph2 queries

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

Is there a JavaScript library to write properly formatted Phonograph2 queries?

Comment: it wouldn't surprise me that someone built something in the past for this, but I'm not aware of anything available atm. Why querying phonograph directly? Could you use OSS instead, and run your queries via Functions? If you do these in Functions you'll get your code tracked properly and nicer dev experience.

Comment: If at all possible, I would recommend building application writeback with Actions and bringing data into Slate via the Ontology API in Foundry Functions, rather than using the Phonograph2 endpoints.

Comment: I started with Foundry functions but hit limitations on length of time for function execution, fuzzy match on array properties, search arounds for aggregations, etc. I also couldn't find a way to form wildcard search in the Foundry Functions as it's done in the Object Explorer.